# self-references in an entity class DataAnnotations core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, self-reference, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to translate this to a DataAnnotations

```
HasOptional(x => x.ParentEntity)
.WithMany(parentEntity => parentEntity.childrenEntities)
.HasForeignKey(childrenEntity => childrenEntity.ParentEntityId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Here is my problem, I have an entity which has a reference to itself.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public int? ProductParentId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ProductParentId")]
    [InverseProperty("childrenProducts")]
    public virtual Product ParentProduct { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductParentId")]
    public virtual List<Products> childrenProducts{ get; set; }
}
```

But I keep getting errors saying that Invalid relationship has been specified using InversePropertyAttribute and ForeignKeyAttribute and that the values are different.

Here is my table:

Product Table

```
ProductId   ProductName ProductParentId 
1           Test        Null
2           Test 1      1
3           Test 2      1
```

What I'm expecting is to get the products and their children, Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove one of the `ForeignKey` attributes - looks like EF gets confused by the duplicate FK definition. And in general forget about data annotations - fluent API are the EF Core preferred way and many things can be done only with fluent API (although this is not one of them).

Comment: Hi, I can't forget them because they are part of the standard we are using as a company.

Comment: Well, if your company wants to use EF Core, then it has to adjust the standards at some point sooner or later. The same way as EF6 edmx format and automatic migrations have been retired in EF Core , more and more things will be available only via fluent API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key doesn't belong to the list. Use InverseProperty instead

```
[InverseProperty("ParentProduct")]
public virtual List<Products> childrenProducts{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi, tried it but it won't return anything for the childrenProducts list.

Comment: So it's not giving an error but incomplete results? Can you describe your test in more detail? Did you properly include children in the query, is the list null vor empty ...?

Comment: The query is returning everything on the product table. But the childrenProductList is returning the same product instead of the children

Comment: I got, thank you. I had to removed the other Inverse Property I had